# HDMI fails to connect to Sony Bravia TV

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, sony

I just hooked a Sony Bravia TV up to my Ubuntu 19.10 laptop, but the TV just says no signal. There are two HDMI ports on the back of the TV, four in the settings, and I've tried each of the eight combinations with the same result.

If I go to Display Settings in Ubuntu, it can identify "Sony SONY TV", but the first toggle is off, which seems weird. If I toggle it on, it can see resolutions ranging from 1920x1080 to 800x600.

As far as xrandr and get-edid, I'm not familiar with either of these but the latter seems more helpful.

Here's a [pastebin of the outputs of each](https://pastebin.com/6yek3i6D).

Many thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: I have the same problem since 19.10 (and now in 20.04), and I'm so tired about this fail. I tried everything and I can't fix it. The laptop uses a Nvidia graphic?

Comment: I never used my Sony Bravia with Linux so far, but I know it works as a Monitor on my Raspberry Pi and it works on the same (dual boot) PC with Microsoft Windows. I have tried everything I can imagine to make it work on Ubuntu 20.04 now, but without success so far.